# Unable to compile OpenCV with OpenVino inference, cpuid.txt cannot be read

Tags: c++, opencv, openvino

I am trying to compile OpenCV with OpenVino inference as explained here:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Intel's-Deep-Learning-Inference-Engine-backend

but when I try to generate the MSVC (2017) project on windows, I am getting this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/local/Intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/inference_engine/src/extension/cmake/CPUID.cmake:324 (file):
  file STRINGS file "C:/local/opencv-build/cpuid.txt" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/local/Intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/inference_engine/src/extension/cmake/feature_defs.cmake:17 (include)
  C:/local/Intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.445/deployment_tools/inference_engine/src/extension/CMakeLists.txt:9 (include)
```

Tools used:

- OpenCV 4.0.0 source code
- OpenVino 5.0.1
- Visual Studio 2017
- CMake-Gui 3.13

Comment: Why aren't you following the [official installation guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-Windows)? I think OpenVino setup comes with a predefined version of OpenCV.

Comment: @zindarod The official version is a dll version for VS and I want to build OpenCV with Inference engine and in static form. I want to build an application that I can ship as one *.exe file in windows.

Comment: Try this workaround: https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/issues/20#issuecomment-447283964. Or use command line CMake.

Comment: Well, have you checked if the file `C:/local/opencv-build/cpuid.txt` exists and is accessible ?

Comment: @Mat No it doesn't exist and I don't know why it was not generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed inappropriate versions for some tools.
Please try to use CMake 3.4 or higher, which is required to build the Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO.

Please try to follow the steps from "https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Install-Windows" for installation and verify whether you are able to compile OpenCV with OpenVino inference.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [forum post](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/computer-vision/topic/780454#comment-1933042) over on OpenVino that indicates some hacky solution to this problem. Here's the suggested solution:

In `...\Intel\computer_vision_sdk_2018.5.456\deployment_tools\inference_engine\src\extension\cmake\CPUID.cmake` (assuming you followed the default OpenVino Toolkit installation, otherwise you'd need to first locate that file from where you installed it), try making the following change on line 251:

```
// std::ofstream fo(\"cpuid.txt\"); old line
std::ofstream fo(\"${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cpuid.txt\");
```

<sup>*Make sure the variable name `fo` is consistent with the code following it.</sup>

This can potentially avoid having inconsistent paths as the line 319 of that same file gets the text file like this:

```
set(_CPUID_INFO "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cpuid.txt")
```

From the stack trace, it seems like your `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` variable is set to `C:/local/opencv-build`, so you should expect `cpuid.txt` to be generated there.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this error, but I changed this line of **CPUID.cmake** as shown in the followng:

```
if(HAVE_CPUID_INFO)
    set(_CPUID_INFO "/home/huihui/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2018.4.420/inference_engine/build/cpuid.txt")
```

Now the error is fixed.